# mongodb positional operator in the find part of update()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, positional-operator

I'm trying to update a certain field in my mongodb collection 'users'

Example of a document:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("536d4d3307221f847fbbea49"),
  groups: [
    {
      match_id: "dc3acf1b",
      groupName: "World Cup, Group A",
      score:[0,1]
    },
    {
      match_id: "d4f14940",
      groupName: "World Cup, Group A",
      score:[2,1]
    }],
  name:"Foo Bar",
  points:10
}
```

I'm trying to update only score fields that have a certain score..

here is what I want (position operator) :

```js
db.users.update({'groups.match_id':i_match , 'groups.score':i_score},
                {$inc:{points:1}});
```

Now I figure this would look for a user that has both those fields, but I want to look in the same groups object that had the first part of the query.

As in:

```js
 db.users.update({'groups.match_id':d4f14940 , 'groups.score':[2,1]},
                    {$inc:{points:1}});
```

should give the user +1 points

But:

```js
 db.users.update({'groups.match_id':dc3acf1b , 'groups.score':[2,1]},
                        {$inc:{points:1}});
```

Should not

You get my drift :)

Now I know from the [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) that I should use the '$' sign, but I think that can only be used in the second paramater of the update() - the updating part..and not the finding part

**note** - The actual comparison of the score in this way (arrays) might not work..but that's not the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator. This allows you to select array elements that require multiple fields to match a condition:

```js
db.users.update(
    { "groups": { 
        "$elemMatch": {
          "match_id": "d4f14940",
          "score": [2,1]
        }      
    }},
    { "$inc": { "points": 1 } }
)
```

So that allows you to match the document as the "groups" array contains an element that has both `match_id` and `score` that meet the conditions you supplied. If you change that `match_id` without altering the score, then the document does not match and the increment is not made to your `points` value.

So this has nothing to do with the positional `$` operator in this case as you are not updating and array at a matched position, which is what that is for.